# Textview is too low in layout

Tags: android

I'm using a TextView in my layout, in an Android Project. I want the TextView to start under the logo, on top of the page. How ever, it starts in the middle of the page. I coded the exact same as all my other pages, where the TextView starts on the right place. I don't know what I can do differently. Does anyone know why this is, or/and how I can fix this? This is an image of my lay-out, currently with the text in the middle of the screen, while I want it to be on top.

[image: Click here to see the image]

This is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Nieuws" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
 </FrameLayout>

     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_nieuws"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:autoLink="web" />

</ScrollView>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main activity code:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NieuwsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nieuws);

        findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_nieuws);
        text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> Naar het nieuwsoverzicht </a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {


            case R.id.button11:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/RKZ.BrandwondencentrumBeverwijk");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                break;
            case R.id.button12:
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/user/rodekruisziekenhuis/featured");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/rodekruiszh?lang=nl");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
                break;
            case R.id.button14:
                Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com/company/rode-kruis-ziekenhuis");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                intent = new Intent(NieuwsActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Read the text above my code, i clearly state what I want there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line in your textview:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

to

```
android:layout_gravity="top"
```

Comment: This indeed made it go upwards, on the right high length. Now the text starts on the far left of the screen, instead of leaving some space on the left side. I'll try to change that with marginLeft. 
Will update when i get the result.

Comment: Used marginLeft with 35 dp. That combined with your answer solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't add a margin (will not be centered on all phones) but you can combine the attributes like this: `android:layout_gravity="top | center_vertical"`

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_gravity' with value 'top | center_vertical').

Comment: oh I'm sorry - just remove the whitespaces

Comment: Used android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical", textview is on top, but not in the center..

Comment: sorry... I made one more mistake... 'center_horizontal' instead of 'vertical'.. SORRY

Comment: Katharina you can't do this to me

Comment: I'm sorry I was very busy and just read your question and thought I could help you...

Comment: Well you did it. It's solved! I forgive you for making so many mistakes ;) thanks for the help love

Answer (score 1):

Changing `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `android:layout_gravity="top"` from the `TextView` should fix it.

From what I can tell, your scrollview is `364p`, and the `TextView` is positioning itself centrally in this. Did you mean to use `android:gravity="center"`, which will centre the contents of the `TextView` rather than the `TextView` itself?

Comment: This indeed made it go upwards, on the right high length. Now the text starts on the far left of the screen, instead of leaving some space on the left side. I'll try to change that with marginLeft. 
Will update when i get the result.

Comment: Yes, the textview should be centered, width whize. From top to bottom it should be top, left to right it should be in the middle.

Comment: Used marginLeft with 35 dp. That combined with your answer solved it. Thanks!